# Query to pull users who clicked on different jobids in one data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am no SQL expert (really, not at all), so I'm having trouble figuring out the SQL to pull users who have clicked on different campaigns into one data extension in Exact Target. I have about 6 job ids that I need to look at. I don't want users who have clicked on ALL but I want users who have clicked on any of those job ids and pull them into one data extension. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SFSE.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select
de.emailaddress
, j.jobname as emailName
, c.eventDate as clickDate
, s.status as SubscriberStatus
from DataExtensionName as de
left join _click as c on (c.subscriberkey = de.emailaddress /*and c.isunique = 1*/) 
left join _subscribers as s (s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid)
left join _job as j on (j.jobid = c.jobid)
where c.jobid in (123,345,456)
```

You can uncomment the `isUnique` part if you want to exclude multiple clicks on a single link

The activity **System Data Views** relate by `JobID`. `SubscriberID` is an internal number that uniquely identifies a subscriber.  It's used to relate the activity data back to the `_Subscribers` data view.  The `SubscriberKey` is the identifier that SFMC uses to keep track of a subscriber's status.  It is also mapped as the sendable field in your **Data Extension**.

One word of caution: Joining multiple system data views together is not very scalable if you have a subscriber-base of more than a few hundred thousand.  If you do, I'd suggest splitting the queries by activity to stay under the 30 minuted Query Activity timeout threshold.

If you query has any kind of *runtime* error, you'll have to contact SFMC Support to determine the source of the error. If you're planning writing more than a few queries, replicating your SFMC schema outside the platform is a good idea. I'd recommend using a local installation **[Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)** or **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)** (using MS SQL Server 2008).

Reference:

[Query Activity (System Data Views)](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)